# Automatically capture clip board data and save it into a file

Tags: java

Capture a image from the clipboard whenever Print screen is pressed and save it in  a file (.doc) using java

Main aim is to copy the data from the clipboard and automatically save it into local disk without going to the desired program (i.e MS Word)- click new - pressing (Ctrl+V) to paste and save it with a name.

The code should perform all of the above three steps automatically.

My Source Code

```
public class CaptureScreenShot {

    private static String DIR  ="C:\\QUIS\\";
    private static JTextField txtDocNumber;
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{
        txtDocNumber = new JTextField();
        Robot robot = new Robot();


        Dimension d = new Dimension(Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize());
        int width = (int) d.getWidth();
        int height = (int) d.getHeight();

        robot.delay(5000);

        Image image = robot.createScreenCapture(new Rectangle(0, 0, width,
                height));
        BufferedImage  bi = new BufferedImage(width, height,
                BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
        Graphics g = bi.createGraphics();
        g.drawImage(image, 0, 0, width, height, null);

        String fileNameToSaveTo = "C:/QUIS/screenCapture_" + createTimeStampStr() + ".PNG";
        String newFile = "C:/QUIS/x" + ".org";
        File newFilee = new File(newFile);

        writeImage(bi, fileNameToSaveTo, "PNG");

        System.out.println("Screen Captured Successfully and Saved to:\n"+fileNameToSaveTo);

        Desktop desktop = Desktop.getDesktop();  
        writeImage(bi, newFile, "org");
        desktop.open(newFilee); 
    }

    public static int writeImage(BufferedImage img, String fileLocation,
            String extension) {
        try {
            BufferedImage bi = img;
            File outputfile = new File(fileLocation);
            ImageIO.write(bi, extension, outputfile);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return 1;
    } 
    public static String createTimeStampStr() throws Exception {
        Calendar mycalendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_hhmmss");
        String timeStamp = formatter.format(mycalendar.getTime());

        return timeStamp;
    }
}
```

Comment: where is your effort?

Comment: To achieve your aim, you need to take some efforts.

Comment: I'm sorry i totally forgot to add my code. Kindly find my code in my edited post above. I have completed till capturing the screen (but only using delay - every 5 seconds it captures) and opening a new file (.org) but due to some reason the image does not get pasted. Kindly share your view.

Answer (score 0):

If you are not particular about a java code, you could use some screen capture tool instead. Snagit is a good tool. You could find it on http://www.techsmith.com/snagit.html

Comment: But it is paid one which is why i'm looking to develop one and make our job easier.

Answer (score 0):

Try this sample code, according to your question it will copy contents from clipboard and will generate image file

```
Clipboard clipboard = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getSystemClipboard();
    try {
        //Get data from clipboard and assign it to an image.
        //clipboard.getData() returns an object, so we need to cast it to a BufferdImage.
        BufferedImage image = (BufferedImage)clipboard.getData(DataFlavor.imageFlavor);

        //file that we'll save to disk.
        File file = new File("image.jpg");

        //class to write image to disk.  You specify the image to be saved, its type,
        // and then the file in which to write the image data.
        ImageIO.write(image, "jpg", file);
    }
```

Comment: Hey thanks a lot, it helped me.. now i'am into opening a new word document and paste this image which is my primary purpose of this idea.